# Adding lines certain lines arent found BASH

Tags: bash, awk

So imagine I have a file which contains sine data such as

```
567
568
570
572
```

But I want to print it out with the missing indexes (569, 571) included.

Essentially placing in the missing numbers, I'm already using awk to read through the file and perform an action for each line

```
(something like awk  '{print #the command im doing on the line}' )
```

So, is there a way I could do this inside awk? I'm very new to bash scripting, I was trying to use a ctr variable and match it to the value of the line but I was struggling to get it to work. (Id prefer not to have the answer given to me rather the technique or functions which may help me achieve my goal)

Answer (score 2):

The following `awk` command processes all input lines as well as any missing integers implied by the gaps in the numbers between consecutive input lines:

```
awk '
  prev > 0 && prev + 1 < $1 {   # Is there a gap between this and the previous no?
    for (i=prev+1; i<$1; ++i) { # Process all numbers in the gap.
      print "filled in: " i
    } 
  } 
  {          
    print "provided: " $1  # Process this number.
    prev=$1                # Remember this number for the next iteration.
  }
  ' input.txt
```

- I'm using `$1`, the first whitespace-separated field on each line, as the number. If your lines contain no other fields (are composed of numbers only), `$0` - the entire input line - would work, too.
- Uninitialized variables in `awk` default to 0, so `prev` - the variable containing the *previous* number - is 0 while processing the very first line, so we must skip the gap check for the first line with condition `prev > 0`.
- The `&& prev + 1 < $1` part of the condition is not strictly needed, as the `for` loop inside the action implicitly enforces the same condition, but I've added it for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `comm`:

#### input.txt

```
567
568
570
572
```

#### all.txt (generated by `seq 567 572`)

```
567
568
569
570
571
572
```

#### bash command

```
# easy way
comm -13 input.txt all.txt
# awk way
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next};$0 in a{next;};1' input.txt all.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but it's easier to write it than tell you how to write it:

```
$ awk '!s{s=$0} {e=$0} END{for (i=s;i<=e;i++) print i}' file
567
568
569
570
571
572
```

I'm sure you can figure it out...